# ADT bundle Android tutorial : Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'hint' with value '@string/edit_message')

Tags: android, eclipse

My attempt to work through Google's Android tutorial has been a real nightmare.

I am using the Eclipse Android Bundle from Google's website. In following the tutorial I had to create a file called fragment_main.xml because it was missing from the project.

I created it as a LinearLayout fragent file, but when I paste in the code from the tutorial I get this error "error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'hint' with value 
 '@string/edit_message')."

This page shows the code:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html

This page shows the bundle I am using:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: First of all, Dont use Eclipse for Android, download Android Studio because Google has announced Android Studio is the supported tool for writing Android apps here on out, plus, Android Studio is 100 times better than Eclipse. Second of all, you shouldn't dive directly into the Training tutorial section, you should get yourself familiar with different concepts first (Obviously, you are having some issue with the String resource not being found here), click [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html). If you want fix that error, open the value folder within the res directory...

Comment: ...then open up the "strings.xml" file, add this to that file `<string name="edit_message">Edit Message</string>. Should fix it your issue. You can down Android Studio IDE [here](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you didn't create a "Blank Activity with a Fragment" when using the "New Android Application" wizard.

I had a look at that documentation, and it tells you to just make a "Blank Activity" in the first part. This means you need to be working with `activity_main.xml` and not `fragment_main.xml`. (Yes, the tutorial is incorrect there.) The [documentation on Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) will explain why this is, but the short story is that you can make your app using an Activity or using a couple Fragments. (Ignore this for now, though!)

As a side note, unless you're using an older device, you should set the "Minimum Required SDK" in the "New Android Application" wizard to "API 14: Android 4.0" if you're using Fragments. If you don't it will require the compatibility libraries which you may not have installed. (In my test here, it needed them with API 11/Honeycomb, too.)

Finally, as noted in the comments above, Android Studio is getting to be the better IDE. However, the tutorial you're using is written for Eclipse, so you may want to stick with Eclipse for now.